# Applying FooTable break point to column header in Grid View after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview, footable

I would like to add and initialize `FooTable` on a `GridView` after the page has rendered.

Given the code:

```
<table class="footable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="8" rules="all" border="1" id="cpContent_gvWorkOrderListing" style="color:#666666;border-style:Double;width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;">
<tr align="center" style="color:White;background-color:#939598;font-size:12px;">
    <th class="gridHiddenColumn" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
    <th class="gridHiddenColumn" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
    <th align="center" scope="col" style="width:4%;"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$cpContent$gvWorkOrderListing&#39;,&#39;Sort$SlNo&#39;)" style="color:White;">Sl No.</a></th>
    <th align="center" scope="col" style="width:10%;"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$cpContent$gvWorkOrderListing&#39;,&#39;Sort$WorkOrderNo&#39;)" style="color:White;">WorkOrder Number</a></th>
    <th align="center" scope="col" style="width:8%;"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$cpContent$gvWorkOrderListing&#39;,&#39;Sort$AssignTo&#39;)" style="color:White;">Assigned To</a></th>
    <th align="center" scope="col" style="width:4%;"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$cpContent$gvWorkOrderListing&#39;,&#39;Sort$Status&#39;)" style="color:White;">Status</a></th>
    <th align="center" scope="col" style="width:8%;"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$cpContent$gvWorkOrderListing&#39;,&#39;Sort$ExternalReferenceId&#39;)" style="color:White;">External RefID</a></th>
    <th align="center" scope="col" style="width:8%;"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$cpContent$gvWorkOrderListing&#39;,&#39;Sort$CustomerNo&#39;)" style="color:White;">Account Number</a></th>
    <th align="center" scope="col" style="width:10%;"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$cpContent$gvWorkOrderListing&#39;,&#39;Sort$CustomerName&#39;)" style="color:White;">Customer Name</a></th>
    <th align="center" scope="col" style="width:5%;"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$cpContent$gvWorkOrderListing&#39;,&#39;Sort$BuildingNo&#39;)" style="color:White;">BuildingNo</a></th>
    <th align="center" scope="col" style="width:10%;"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$cpContent$gvWorkOrderListing&#39;,&#39;Sort$StreetName&#39;)" style="color:White;">Street Name</a></th>
    <th align="center" scope="col" style="width:6%;"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$cpContent$gvWorkOrderListing&#39;,&#39;Sort$City&#39;)" style="color:White;">City</a></th>
    <th align="center" scope="col" style="width:5%;"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$cpContent$gvWorkOrderListing&#39;,&#39;Sort$WorkOrderDate&#39;)" style="color:White;">WorkOrder Date</a></th>
    <th align="center" scope="col" style="width:5%;"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$cpContent$gvWorkOrderListing&#39;,&#39;Sort$DueDate&#39;)" style="color:White;">Due Date</a></th>
    <th align="center" scope="col" style="width:8%;">Note1</th>
    <th align="center" scope="col" style="width:8%;">Note2</th>
</tr>
```

I want to modify the attributes of

```
    <th align="center" scope="col" style="width:4%;"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$cpContent$gvWorkOrderListing&#39;,&#39;Sort$Status&#39;)" style="color:White;">Status</a></th>
```

to be

```
    <th  data-hide="phone,tablet" align="center" scope="col" style="width:4%;"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$cpContent$gvWorkOrderListing&#39;,&#39;Sort$Status&#39;)" style="color:White;">Status</a></th>
```

and then initialize FooTable after the header gets modified.

I think this will give me the anchor:

```
$('a').filter(function(index) { return $(this).text() === "Status"; }
```

and this will add the attribute:

```
$("th").attr("data-hide", "phone,tablet");
```

But I'm drawing a blank on combining them to accomplish my task.

Comment: is there a reason you want to modify the header _after_ render instead of in the code behind?

Answer (score 0):

Adding html markup in the code behind is trivial since every postback re-renders the entire page.  Databinding events may or may not get triggered so I'm using the GridView's `PreRender` event to add "last-chance" markup as opposed to its `DataBound` or `RowDataBound` events

```
// VB Code - convert as necessary
Private Sub gvWorkOrderListing_PreRender(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles gvWorkOrderListing.PreRender

  Dim hrc As TableCellCollection = gvList.HeaderRow.Cells

  For idx As Int32 = 0 To hrc.Count - 1

    // Modify condition to single out relevant columns
    // This is based in what I see in your rendered table
    If idx > 1 Then
      hrc(idx).Attributes("data-hide") = "phone,tablet"
    End If

  Next
End Sub
```